# inheriting private variable in python

Tags: python, inheritance

When inheriting in python, i got following error with private variables:

> AttributeError: 'dog' object has no attribute '_dog__name'

I searched a lot but didn't understand where my problem is;

```
class animal(object):
    __name = ""
    __height = ""
    __weight = ""
    __sound = ""

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound


    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm and {} weight and say {}.".format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound)

class dog(animal):
    __owner = ""

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super(dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm and {} weight and say {} and belongs to {}.".format(self.__name, self.__height,
                                                                                self.__weight, self.__sound,
                                                                                self.__owner)

puppy = dog('puppy', 45, 15, 'bark', 'alex')

puppy.toString()
```

Comment: no, it's about variables, not methods.

Comment: The mechanism is the same. Heck, it even affects local variables and imported modules inside a class statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create var with double underscore, its just a notation use to indicate it as private variable, python do name mangling on the variable name itself to prevent normal way access to it.

However, its still not the real private variable like C/C++. You can still access the so called python "private var" with syntax below

```
var = __myvar
# access with _<class name>__myvar
```

From [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),

- _single_leading_underscore : weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an
  underscore.
- __double_leading_underscore : when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes _FooBar__boo

For your case, change your dog class toString method to below then it should works

```
def toString(self):
    return "{} is {} cm and {} weight and say {} and belongs to {}.".format(self._animal__name, self._animal__height,
                                                                                self._animal__weight, self._animal__sound,
                                                                                self.__owner) # __owner remains because its not inherit from class animal
```

another option is to change your animal class variable to single underscore `_` if you don't really need double underscore `__`

Comment: tnx, is it the same for python 3 and 2?

Comment: I think so, it should be same for python 2 and 3

Comment: cuz in this video, the instructor runs exactly the same code without any error; https://youtu.be/N4mEzFDjqtA?t=39m44s

Comment: i have tested with my python3.2, it behave the same with python2, python 3 documentation `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html` shows the same for name mangling, no idea why it works from the video